# C# StackExchange.Redis operation for existence by key array

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

From the StackExchange.Redis library I've seen that there is an operation (`KeyExists`) that checks how many keys exist from a key array, but I haven't found an operation that checks key by key without retrieving the whole value, like a `Dictionary<string, bool>`.

Is there a simple workaround to do that or a command in Redis that I can use with this library?

Answer (score 0):

[Looking at the source](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/ae6419a164600b4b54dd7ce8a699efe8e98d8f1c/src/StackExchange.Redis/RedisDatabase.cs#L814-L818), the underlying Redis command is [`EXISTS`](https://redis.io/commands/exists/) which is plainly documented to

> [returns] the number of keys that exist from those specified as arguments. [...]
> If the same existing key is mentioned in the arguments multiple times, it will be counted multiple times.

so that won't help you there.

You could

- write a custom [Lua script](https://redis.io/docs/manual/programmability/lua-api/) that calls `EXISTS` internally for the keys passed in and returns the extant ones as a list
- call `KeyExists` with a single parameter multiple times in a pipeline and collate the answers (e.g. if you call `KeyExists` for `a`, `b`, `c` and they return 1, 0, 1, you'd know `a` and `c` exist).